# In email attachment any type of document file is sent with File extension instead of coreect extension

Tags: java, file-io, smtp, amazon-s3

I am fetching S3 objects and then sending the object in email as an attachment. I am saving the contents in a temporary file. For images the code is working fine but in case of documents (pdf, docx, csv) files the attachments are sent without extension so they are not accessible.

```
 try {
            fullObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
            System.out.println("fullObject: " + fullObject);
            ObjectMetadata metadata = fullObject.getObjectMetadata();
            System.out.println(" meta data type: " + metadata.getContentType());
            InputStream inputStream = fullObject.getObjectContent();

            String extension = fullObject.getKey();
            int index = extension.lastIndexOf('.');
            if(index > 0) {
                extension = extension.substring(index + 1);
                System.out.println("File extension is " + extension);
            }

            File file = File.createTempFile(key, "."+ extension );
            System.out.println("file: "+ file);
            try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error in copying data from one file to another");

            }
            dataSource = new FileDataSource(file);
            System.out.println("added datasource in the list");
            attachmentsList.add(dataSource);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon going through this code, I got to know that the issue was not in this code but when I was setting the name of the File. I was setting filename without any extension, for example I set Filename as "temporary" this caused the documents to be saved with tmp extension. All I had to do was add the extension of the object with its name ("temporary.docx"), this solved the issue and attachments were sent properly and were accessible.